# Unable to Unwrap 3D object

Tags: texturing, uv

I imported an SVG, extruded it and now it's a 3D object, and I want to add a texture from a JPG.  I have a photo of some glasses that I'd like to recreate as a 3D model.

I followed all the instructions on Unwrapping and UV Editing, but I can't get the Unwrap menu / options to appear.

I have my object in Edit mode, I press A to select all, and when I press U, nothing happens.  I've been searching everywhere for an answer but have come up short.

I know it's a super basic thing, but it's driving me nuts!  (I'm new here).  Please help.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't really have much experience with it, but the fact is that you can't uv-unwrap curves, only meshes!

Answer (score 0):

As impresso says, you need to convert your curve to mesh: Select your object in *Object* mode and go into the Object menu > *Convert to* > *Mesh from Curve*.

Comment: Thanks you @impresso and moonboots !  Worked perfectly once I converted to a mesh :)